# Is CryptoCurrency Undoubtedly Acceptable in all the way?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, fiqh

I need clear picture about the acceptability by Islamic Shariya Council about the trade by any of the Crypto  Currency ? Still few Muslim brothers around the world stating me : Involving with CryptoCurency is RIBA as Per Islami Shariya.

Grateful please give some Quranic & Sunnah Evidence in Crypto Currensy's favor.

Jazak Allah

Comment: We have posts on this and similar topics (bitcoins) on the site, I'm no expert, so either you may find an answer on that here or it is a matter where you should refer to a mufti who is capable to do ijtihad and give a fatwa.

Comment: To be sure you should consult an authoritative source: get a fatwa from a reputable Mufti. The question is a duplicate as it has been asked before, any answers given may or may not be correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Bitcoin a halal investment instrument?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7961/is-bitcoin-a-halal-investment-instrument)